# Not being able to filter json data by just name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a file called `data.json` and a file called `Search.html`. The xbox360 json file contains:

```
[{
    "Name": "Assassin's Creed: Rogue",
    "Image": "Images/360ACR.jpg",
    "Platform": "XBOX 360"
}, {
    "Name": "Battlefield 3",
    "Image": "Images/360BF3.jpg",
    "Platform": "XBOX 360"
}]
```

The Search html file contains:

```
<html>    
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#search').keyup(function() {
                    var searchField = $('#search').val();
                    var regex = new RegExp(searchField, "i");
                    var output = '<div class="row">';
                    var count = 1;
                    $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
                        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                            if ((val.Name.search(regex) != -1) || (val.Platform.search(regex) != -1)) {
                                output += '<div class="col-md-6 well">';
                                output += '<div class="col-md-3"><img class="img-responsive" src="' + val.Image + '" alt="' + val.Name + '" /></div>';
                                output += '<div class="col-md-7">';
                                output += '<h5>' + val.Name + '</h5>';
                                output += '<p>' + val.Platform + '</p>'
                                output += '</div>';
                                output += '</div>';
                                if (count % 2 == 0) {
                                    output += '</div><div class="row">'
                                }
                                count++;
                            }
                        });
                        output += '</div>';
                        $('#results').html(output);
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form>
            <div class="form">
                <input type="text" class="" id="search" placeholder="Search">
                <input type="button" id="search" value="Search" />
            </div>
        </form>
        <div id="results"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The problem with this code is that when the user types `a` or any letter into the textbox it brings up all the data from the JSON file. I just want it to filter it by name. So if I type `Assassins Creed` it just brings up that game only.

I know this question is tedious with the amount of code I have put in. It would be nice for someone to help me. I appreciate it if you can. I am trying by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a filter:

```
var res = data.filter(function(obj){
    return obj.Name.indexOf(input) >= 0;
});
```

The array of objects you want will be in `res`.
Replace `input` with the string you want to check for.

See this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4b5gffmu/

Comment: Thanks Arg0n for your response. What shall i replace this with? or where will i put this piece of code?

Comment: The first line in the callback from `$.getJSON`. When you get back `data`. Continue working with `res` instead of `data` after that. (Before `$.each`)

Comment: Sorry this broke my code. So it will appear like this - $.getJSON('data.json', function(res) {
   
   var res = data.filter(function(obj){
    return obj.Name.indexOf(Name) >= 0;
});

Comment: No, you should still get back `data`. Not `res`. `function(data){ var res ... }`

Comment: I debugged - SyntaxError: expected expression, got keyword 'var'. Not very useful this debugging. And no data is displaying.

Comment: I'd suggest posting your code on e.g. jsfiddle.net and link to that so i can have a look at what your code looks now. As the error states, you have a syntax error somewhere.

Comment: I've made a JSFiddle to show how this is supposed to work. Look at updated answer.

Comment: Thank you for all your help. I got it solved finally.

Comment: No problem! Mark as answer please if this helped you.

Comment: Oh yeah, since this works for the one json file can i do it for multiple files. for example bring up assassin creed for all consoles. I have a 360.json file, xboxone.json file, ps3.json file etc.

Comment: Yes, you would have to load the data from all files first though ofcourse.